Existence of a sequence whose norm is the same as a given functional

Let denote $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : a_n = 2^{-n} $, $a:=(a_n) \in l_1$ and $f_a : c_0 \rightarrow \Bbb{K}, x = (x_n) \rightarrow \sum_n a_n x_n = \sum_n \frac{x_n}{2^n} $ . ¿Can we find some $x = (x_n) \in c_0 $ such that $\lVert x \rVert_\infty = 1$ and $f_a(x) = \lVert f_a \rVert$ ?

I am almost sure that we cannot since, knowing that $c_0'$ is isometric to $l_1$ we know that  $\lVert f_a \rVert = \lVert a \rVert_1 = 1 $, so we must find an $x=(x_n) \in c_0$ such that $\sum_n \frac{x_n}{2^n} = 1$ . The problem is that I think that the only sequence that satisfies this is $x_n=1$ which is not in $c_0$, so we would finished, but I do not know how to justify it, so any possible help or advice would be appreciated.

What do you mean by $\sum_na_nx_n=\sum$?

@JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I miswrote it, I have updated correctly

Are you using the norm condition? It appears to me that if one term is smaller than one and no term can be bigger than one, the whole series would have to be smaller than one.

@AlexMoreno I thought it, but as an inequality like: $|\sum_n \frac{x_n}{2^n} | \leq \sum_n |\frac{x_n}{2^n}| \leq \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$ , so it gives only a less or equal, is there something to do to use this to make strictly less?

More general fact holds. For $a\in\ell^1$ let $A=\{n\,:\, a_n\neq 0\}.$ If $A$ is infinite then for any $x\in c_0$ such that $\|x\|_\infty=1,$ we have $$\left |\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n\right |<1$$ Indeed, fix $x\in c_0$ such that $\|x\|_\infty =1.$ As $\lim_k x_k=0,$ there is $K$ such that $|x_k|\le 1/2$ for $k\ge K.$ Since $A$ is infinite it contains $n_0\ge K,$ i.e. $|a_{n_0}|>0.$ Then  $$\left |\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n\right |\le  \sum_{n\neq n_0}^\infty |a_n|\,|x_n|+|a_{n_0}|\,|x_{n_0}|\\ \le\sum_{n\neq n_0}^\infty |a_n|+{1\over 2}|a_{n_0}|  =|a\|_1-{1\over 2}|a_{n_0}|<\|a\|_1$$

Sorry but you say that there is an index such that the value of the sequence is greater than $1$ and this is not necessarily true. In fact, in my sequence which is all less or equal than $1$ this does not hold. $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : \frac{1}{2^n} \leq 1$ . Despite of this, I think that the argument works omitting it, so thanks!

Sorry for the misprint. Corrected
